# ActiveMQ Unexpected failure from FailoverTransport

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, failover

I have a (fairly) complicated Java app that uses Camel (2.11.0) and ActiveMQ (5.8.0) to send messages between a Camel route and various ActiveMQ queues. The Camel-ActiveMQ endpoint that I am using defines a failover like so:

```
failover:(tcp://myBroker01.example.com:61616)?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1&randomize=false&maxReconnectDelay=250
```

You'll notice I only have 1 broker defined; for now I only have 1 broker (and so that kind of cancels out the usefulness of the failover transport), but down the road I may have several brokers as part of this failover URI.

When I run my app, I see the following error in my app logs:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: <com.me.myapp.model.WidgetVO>
    ...middle portion of stack trace omitted for brevity; probably irrelevant
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Unexpected failure.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1409)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1496)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:325)
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.ConnectionPool$2.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:105)
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.ConnectionPool$2.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:174)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:457)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected failure.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.oneway(FailoverTransport.java:620)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1380)
    ... 85 more
```

So it looks like Camel is correctly reading my failover transport configuration and is attempting to asynchronously send (`oneway(...)`) a serialized `WidgetVO` message to my queue. I searched [GrepCode for line 620 of `FailoverTransport`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.activemq/activemq-client/5.8.0/org/apache/activemq/transport/failover/FailoverTransport.java) and here's the code block that the exception is being thrown from:

```
if (transport == null) {
    // Previous loop may have exited due to use being
    // disposed.
    if (disposed) {
        error = new IOException("Transport disposed.");
    } else if (connectionFailure != null) {
        error = connectionFailure;
    } else if (timedout == true) {
        error = new IOException("Failover timeout of " + timeout + " ms reached.");
    } else {
        error = new IOException("Unexpected failure.");
    }

    break;
}
```

So the `Transport` is NULL, however the message has not been marked for disposal, nor is there a connection failure, nor has our connection to the broker timed out.

Does any of this mean anything to anyone? Can anyone give me some pointers as to how to begin debugging this? I'm happy to post more code if it's needed.

**Update**: Here is another WARN message that I see in my app log *prior* to the exception being thrown:

```
07:53:00,306 WARN  [DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] Rejecting received message because of
the listener container having been stopped in the meantime: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId
= 7, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:<myserver.example.com>, originalDestination = null,
originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:<myserver.example.com>, destination = queue://myQueue,
transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1392295980294, arrival = 0,
brokerInTime = 1392295980297, brokerOutTime = 1392295980298, correlationId = null, replyTo = null,
persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0,
targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null,
marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@2d0b20f5, dataStructure = null,
redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {breadcrumbId=ID-<myserver.example.com>},
readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, text = <com.me.myapp.WidgetVO>
 ...WidgetVO>}
```

I had to obviously change all the server names to `<myserver.example.com>` for security purposes. I thought it was interesting that the `transactionId` is NULL...

Comment: does this ever work?  or do you get the error after some time?

Comment: ports are correct? no firewall or dns issue?

Comment: Thanks @boday (+1) - no this never works, and it fails on the first message. The thing is, this Camel route is packaged inside a WAR and deployed to a Tomcat instance inside our VPN. The ActiveMQ broker is also inside our VPN (same network). And we have other WARs deployed on the same Tomcat instance that don't use the failover transport, but that have no problem connecting to the same ActiveMQ instance.

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve (+1) - yes ports are correct, this is all internal traffic so no firewall/dns/vpn issues, etc. Please see my answer to boday's comment above. Thoughts?

Comment: Everyone: please see my update which includes a WARNing message I am getting just before the exception occurs.